# Woocommerce Order Quantity in Multiples

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to restrict woocommerce to only selling in set quantities of 5, 10 or 15.
The code snippet below ( which i found on this forum) allows me to set a minimum quantity of 5 but i'm wondering if anybody could advise if it can be modified to allow 5, 10 or 15.

I appreciate any help you can offer.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
global $woocommerce;
$minimum = 5;
if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count < $minimum ) {
    $woocommerce->add_error( sprintf( 'Cards can only be purchased in multiples of %s    Please ammend your order.' , $minimum ) );
 }
}
```

Comment: The WooCommerce Advanced Product Quantities allows you to set a step value i.e. if you set it to 10 then customers will only be able to add to cart 100 items or 110 items nothing in the middle. The next valid order quantity will be 120 and so on. For anyone wondering, this is useful when you're shipping items in crates, boxes with dozens of items in each.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Gareth for his answer, but i actually found a better way of achieving what i need, just posting in case anybody else needs it.

I found it better to restrict the cart to sell in multiples of 5 which can be achieved with the following code.

```
// check that cart items quantities totals are in multiples of 5
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'woocommerce_check_cart_quantities' );
function woocommerce_check_cart_quantities() {
  global $woocommerce;
  $multiples = 5;
    $total_products = 0;
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $total_products += $values['quantity'];
    }
    if ( ( $total_products % $multiples ) > 0 )
        $woocommerce->add_error( sprintf( __('You need to buy in quantities of %s products', 'woocommerce'), $multiples ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce Allow Checkout in Multiples Only, To force the customer to add multiples of a certain quantity to the cart before being able to checkout

```
<?php
// check that cart items quantities totals are in multiples of 6
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'woocommerce_check_cart_quantities' );
function woocommerce_check_cart_quantities() {
    $multiples = 6;
    $total_products = 0;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $total_products += $values['quantity'];
    }
    if ( ( $total_products % $multiples ) > 0 )
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __('You need to buy in quantities of %s products', 'woocommerce'), $multiples ), 'error' );
}

// Limit cart items with a certain shipping class to be purchased in multiple only
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'woocommerce_check_cart_quantities_for_class' );
function woocommerce_check_cart_quantities_for_class() {
    $multiples = 6;
    $class = 'bottle';
    $total_products = 0;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $product = get_product( $values['product_id'] );
        if ( $product->get_shipping_class() == $class ) {
            $total_products += $values['quantity'];
        }
    }
    if ( ( $total_products % $multiples ) > 0 )
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __('You need to purchase bottles in quantities of %s', 'woocommerce'), $multiples ), 'error' );
}
?>
```

Comment: I found this answer to be very helpful. I didn't need the second action (pertaining to shipping classes), but it's nice to know how to do it. This is the modern answer, and should be the accepted one, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but this should work, basically just added the different minimums into an array so the check for $minimum will check all 3 amounts

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
global $woocommerce;
$minimum = array('5,'10','15');
if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count < $minimum ) {
    $woocommerce->add_error( sprintf( 'Cards can only be purchased in multiples of %s    Please ammend your order.' , $minimum ) );
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work, it actually kills the entire site from loading. I ran it through a php checker and it shows "PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting ')' in your code on line 4
$minimum = array('5,'10','15');"

Comment: Ok on closer inspection i noticed a missing ' just after the 5 in the array, so now that is allowing the site to load, but unfortunately the function isn't actually working. It displays the warning regardless of whether i have 5 items or 10 items, it still prevents checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Try using WooCommerce Advanced Product Quantities, it should take care of this for you. Otherwise the below functions are what it uses to get the right step and minimum values for both the cart and product page. Keep in mind that if you only change the input values you'll have to validate them on add to cart and checkout (again the plugin linked below does all of this for you).

http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-incremental-product-quantities/

Otherwise this filter would probably help for the cart:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 'input_step_value', 1, 2);

function input_step_value( $default, $product ) {
     return 5;
}
```

And this one for the product page:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'input_set_all_values', 1, 2 );

function input_set_all_values( $args, $product ) {
     $args['step'] = 5;     
     $args['min_value'] = 5;
     return $args;
}
```