# Filter to check quantity at checkout woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to use the code in this old thread.
[Filter to check quantity at checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211084/filter-to-check-quantity-at-checkout)
But i get an error with the woocommerce->add_error() part.

There seem to be some deprecated code in this, can someone help me spot those for a new code working for newest version of wordpress/woocomerce?

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Hello i get the error
"Fatal error: Call to undefined method WooCommerce::wc_add_notice()"

Comment: Have you declared `global $woocommerce;` ??

Answer (score 1):

I think `add_error()` is no longer in `woocommerce` you should use `wc_add_notice` .visit [this](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202241985-Fatal-error-Call-to-undefined-method-WooCommerce-add-error-.)
may help you.